# Single Image WMS in GeoServer to clear duplicate labels

Tags: geoserver, wms, labeling, openlayers-2

I have set up GeoServer with PostgreSQL/PostGIS as database.
Imported a country boundary shapefile into the database and published as WMS.
The data has got the Country name attribute in the **"label"** column.
I setup a map client using Openlayers, and it shows so many labels when zoomed in, one for each tile.

Can I publish the wms map as a **Single Image**, (without multiple image tiles) to *avoid duplicate* country name labels?

Or is there any other successful methods to do this in SLD?

I have read many answers and tried vendor options to correct this, nothing worked.
Some similar questions were seen as removed as duplicates, but sincerely, I got no solution for this duplicate label issue in GeoServer.

**More Info:**
I am using GeoServer 2.7.0
Using openlayers javascript from :

> http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js

And the Openlayers code is:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     var map;
>     function init() {
>         map = new OpenLayers.Map({
>             div: "map",
>             projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
>             controls: [],
>             numZoomLevels: 8,
>             maxZoomLevel: 16
>         });
>         var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Open Street");
>         var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets");
> ```

```
        Layer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("1648", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", 
        { layers: 'my_wor:Layer1', transparent: true },
        { isBaseLayer: false });

        Layer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("2015", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", 
        { layers: 'my_wor:Layer2', transparent: true },
        { isBaseLayer: false });

        map.addLayers([gmap, osm, Layer1, Layer2]);

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
</script>
```

See the SLD below, with the vendor options "**group**" is given true.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Polygon with styled label</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>SLD Cook Book: Polygon with styled label</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#CCCCCC</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>

          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>label</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
            </Font>
         <LabelPlacement>
           <PointPlacement>
             <AnchorPoint>
               <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
               <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
             </AnchorPoint>
           </PointPlacement>
         </LabelPlacement>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <VendorOption name="autoWrap">160</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="repeat">0</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="group">true</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="labelAllGroup">false</VendorOption>

          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>`

Comment: Well try with the Single Image, and see what happen.But it might be that you have multigeometries and that there is a label for each part of the multigeometries. Is this the case?

Comment: How to set up single image? I couldn't find a way in Geoserver admin.  Yes,I am drawing a single multipolygon for the country. Does that make the problem?

Comment: Is this such a tough problem with label duplication or single image wms rendering in Geoserver?

Answer (score 5):

I will try to be as clear as possible, but I am not sure I understood everything that your are asking. You might want to edit your post with additional information or a concrete example and the version of Geoserver you are using.

---

Problem 1: you have duplicate labels due to the tiling of your WMS request by OL

-> solution: in Open Layer, request a single WMS image (see example here http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/wms-image.html)

---

Problem 2: you have duplicate labels due to multi geometries

-> solution: use the vendor option `group` in Geoserver SLD

> The group option allows displaying a single label for multiple
>   features in a logical group.

(see here http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html)

---

These are not miracle solutions and you might still need to tweek your SLD to get exactly what you want.

EDIT – regarding Problem 2

A possible trick I used on a small dataset: manually delete the label value for the smaller entities of my multi-geometries. However, I would not consider this good practice.

Another trick would be to create a additional column in your database and to assign 1 (=need a label) and 0 (=does not need a label) and to use it in a conditional filter in SLD to tell Geoserver whether to draw a label or not

---

EDIT 2

(after the comment from @user30184 & @OpenMapperz)

This is the same example, but for OL3 here http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/wms-image.html?q=wms

If you want to find the relevant syntax, look at the OL3 documentation. The relevant point here is to use the object `ol.layer.Image` with `ol.layer.ImageWMS`.

Comment: I have edited the question adding more details and code snippets.

Comment: The right term is "single tile" and here is on OpenLayers 2 example http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/single-tile.html. You can also compare tiled/single tile settings with the layer preview application (OL3)  that comes with GeoServer. Open the advanced settings of the preview and you will see the menu.

Comment: In Geoserver Layer preview(OL3), the code is like this: 
`      var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          ratio: 1,
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/myworkspace/wms',
          params: {'FORMAT': format,
                   'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                LAYERS: 'myworkspace:mylayername',
                STYLES: '',
          }
        })
      }); `   
What is the relevant syntax to take from this?

Comment: I had the problem of multiple labels on geoserver and openlayer set up changing to ol.layer.Image and ol.layer.ImageWMS solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add  <ogc:Function name="centroid"> with geometry field

t6431_geometry
          
                 
         
           t6431_name
         
         
           Times New Roman
           11
           normal
           bold
         
         
           
             
               0.5
               0.5
             
           
         
         
           #000000
         
         60
         150